# Multiple databases inside localhost connection

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker, using it only for local development, and I'm trying to move from MAMP Pro setup to containers for the portability and ease of setup.

One main problem I can't seem to figure out is how to have multiple databases inside my localhost connection like seen here in Navicat:

[image: Databases under MAMP]

In this example db1 is used by project1, and db2 and db3 are both used by another project2

If I try to make containers in Docker for these projects I have to create a different localhost connection for each one (each with different ports), different volumes (probably) and keep track for the settings for each new database that I need.

Is this pattern of single-connection/multiple-databases doable in Docker?
The closest I've seen is using a reverse proxy so that everything points to a single port, but I couldn't make it work with multiple projects. :/

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ might be a better forum for database Docker questions.

Comment: Yes it is, the database inside the containers are behaving in a same way as they ware installed directly on the OS. All you need to do after starting the docker container, connect to the database server in the container and created the databases. However, better approach is to keep the databases in separate containers. Let me know if you create this question to serverfault.com, I will put the step-by-step process there

Comment: Ok thank you I will post it there when I can :)